# Stabilize a 12V DC supply (from Lipo)

Tags: dc, stability, linear-regulator

I'm newbie in electronics, but I want to learn some basics things.

I have a 12V DC output (from a charging/discharging PCB Lipo battery), and I would like to stabilize it to run a mini-amplifier ([Veleman Kit MK190](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/0/minikits/manuals/manual_mk190.pdf)) and 2x2W speakers. For now, I have lots of parazites.

I have an oscilloscope, the signal is this one, with theses scales:

horizontal: 0.5 µs / div

vertical: 20 mV / div

So Delta V = 60 mV

[image]

**My question:** What is the best way to stabilise it, to have a sound without parazites ?
Does a **L7812 regulator** a good solution ?

In this case, what should be the diagram I could use ?

Can I add a capacitor to filter the signal ?

Thanks

Edit: To precise my question, I havn't the datasheet of the battery, but a photo of the PCB:

[image]

I have plugged the oscilloscope in the 12V output.
The battery can also deliver 5V with the USB port.
You can see a displaced capacitor, because I need space...

Comment: It would help if you can include a circuit diagram of your current setup, and explain what that oscilloscope is measuring.

Comment: Thanks to try to help me! Unfortunately I have not the datasheet of the charge/discharge PCB, it's from a chineese power bank. I can add a photo but I don't think it will help you... The oscilloscope is measuring the variation of the 12V signal, so here 12V +- 30mV

Comment: We don't need to know the internals, just how you've hooked everything up - model the power bank as a battery.

Comment: The power bank is [this one](http://fr.aliexpress.com/item/42000mAh-Power-Bank-Multi-Voltage-5V-12V-16V-19V-External-Battery-Pack-Portable-Charger-For-Phones/32295702252.html), it can delivery 12V or 19V if the charger is plugged or not. This is not good quality, and noname... but works for my use.

Comment: 6 cells, 3S2P configuration

Comment: You should edit your answer to include these details, and a circuit diagram, including any capacitors, filtering, etc, you already have.

Comment: ok I will try to do this.

Comment: 60-80mV at almost 600kHz on your 12V supply shouldn't be audible on your amplifier's output. I don't think you need to worry about it. You could use an LC filter if you really want to though.

Comment: You're right. The sound comes when I start the ARM Board with external 5V. (worst with batt USB 5V). But I think this issue is too difficult for me...

Answer (score 1):

Without a circuit, the suggestion can only be to use a choke to reduce the very sharp and almost invisible thin spikes and then use a linear regulator to stabilise the rest. Keep in mind that you don't need perfectly smooth output, the amplifier is partially insensitive to them, it works (simplifying a lot) as regulator too.

Check also http://www.linear.com/docs/11877 (Minimizing Switching Regulator Residue
in Linear Regulator Outputs) that explains everything. You don't need to achieve the same results, since an audio amplifier is not that sensitive to input voltage, just get the idea behind the article.

Comment: I will try the same test with a ferrite, to see if the spikes are still there, and maybe a regulator. Thanks

Comment: They will be there, just smoother, so that they will hopefully fall within the frequency where the regulator is effective. Use proper capacitors, effective at 1 MHz, too. Right now the spikes are over 20 MHz (thinner than 1/10 of a division), way too much for a regulator.